# Method to remove nodes

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I have a *******, and I'm trying to get my remove method to removes and returns a specific targeted items. I tried a lot of different way trying to make it work, but it keeps giving me the NPE.

Here is my first remove():

Here is my second remove() that was able to make the code compile:

Here is my LinearNode:

Student class:

Comment: What line exactly gives you the NPE?

Comment: private Student items;      //Error line 14   This is what it said: OrderListLinked$LinearNode.access$0(OrderListLinked$LinearNode) line: 14

Comment: Please provide the *whole* error message.

Comment: Like this? Thread [main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException)) 
 OrderListLinked$LinearNode.access$0(OrderListLinked$LinearNode) line: 14

Comment: which one is line 14?

Comment: The one in LinearNode class: private Student items;

Comment: provide the whole stacktrace and put it in your question

Comment: @markusw how do I get the stack trace?

Comment: when the programm crashes it prints out a lot of stuff, doesn't it? And the complete "loveletter" I would like to see

Comment: is there a `compareTo` method for student?

Comment: @markusw Don't know if above is the right stacktrace. When I try to run it, it immediately put me to debug screen and above is all I got. I also tried to get the most update one, and this one somehow don't have line 14 anymore.

Comment: @SHR ah yes, just put it up.

Comment: @Drews: don’t run the program in debug mode if you don’t want to debug. Just run it and copy the console output.

Comment: @Drews Sorry i didn't notice that it was a innerclass. I would suggest that you print items before using compareTo to make sure that they are not null.

Please also provide the full stacktrace so we know which line gives you the nullpointer and point out the row.

Comment: Sorry, can't be any helpful. Above is all it gave me from the Console and just stopped right there. Nothing else displayed.

Comment: @Drews, is there a reason deleted most of your question? It makes it more difficult to learn from the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove should be fairly straightforward and you already have the general idea:

```
public Student remove(Student items) {
    LinearNode  previous = null,
                current = head;

    // iterate over all the nodes starting at the head, maintaining a reference to the previous node as you go          
    while (current != null && current.items.compareTo(items) != 0) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }

    // At this point you have either a) found the Node with matching items or b) not found it
    if (current == null) {
        // not found in the list
        return null;
    }

    // At this point you know where the Node is, and you have a reference previous node as well 
    // so it's easy to reattach the linked list to remove the node
    if (previous == null) {
        // The head node was the match if previous is not set, so make sure to update the head Node accordingly
        head = current.next;
    }
    else {
        previous.next = current.next
    }

    return current.items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch on the suspicious code, till you find which line causing the problem.

This will tell you if you are looking at the right place.

**For Example:**

```
  while (current != null) {
     try{//1st level try
        if(current.items.compareTo(items) == 0) {
          try{ //2nd level try 
            if(previous == null) {
                head = head.next;
                return items;
            }
            else {
                previous.next = current.next;
                return items;
            }
          }catch(NullPointerException e ){
             StackTraceElement t = e.getStackTrace()[0];  
             System.out.println("catch lvl 2 at line: " + t.getLineNumber());
          }
        }
        else {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
      }catch(NullPointerException e){
         StackTraceElement t = e.getStackTrace()[0]; 
         System.out.println("catch lvl 1 at line: " + t.getLineNumber());
      }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

You can try to put this "try catch" and wrap all your main function:

```
try{
  ...
}catch(NullPointerException e ){
  int i=0
  for( StackTraceElement t : e.getStackTrace()){
     System.out.println("stack[" + i + "]: " + t.getLineNumber());
     i++;
  }
}
```

**EDIT2**

```
public Student remove(Integer studentId)
{
    LinearNode previous = null;
    LinearNode current = head;

    while (current != null) {
        //if everything is OK you can remove the 2 ifs 
        if(current.items == null){
           //something is really wrong on insert
        }
        else if(current.items.getId() == null){
           //something is really wrong on insert
        }
        else if( studentId.compareTo(curent.items.getId()) == 0) {

            //return value is curent.items;

            if(previous == null) {
                head = head.next;
                return curent.items;
            }
            else {
                previous.next = current.next;
                return curent.items;
            }
        }
        else {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    //not found!
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will see what I can do with it. I tried the example and did not catch anything.

Comment: If by main function you mean the test driver, then I don't have to worry about it, because it was provided to me by the instructor so I should not even be touching it.

Comment: Ok, so I said that I tried a lot of different remove() to make it works. And there is actually one that was able to let the code compile. But the thing is, instead of removing the elements and thus made it disappear, that method return all the elements that was to be removed. So if you don't mind, would you take a look at my second remove() I just posted and see if it's any better than the first one.

Comment: The real Question is: How can student::items can be null? if you prevent it to be null, the 1st remove will be just fine. 2nd thing, you return the student::items you give as input to the remove function, and it seem you want to get something different. I guess what you really want is to give only student ID and return the items from the list. see edit2